# Error SQL query: Edit Edit SET lc_messages = 'en_US'; MySQL said: Documentation facing error #1193 - Unknown system variable 'lc_messages'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Unable to login through phpmyadmin. Even I am using latest version as follows
php 7.0.10, phpmyadmin 4.6 and mysql5.7.

Note: when I reinstall Wamp, I can able to login through phymyadmin. as i restart my pc, i start getting error.

Answer (score 0):

IF uhave installed mysql before installing wamp,delete that mysql from program files,program files x86,userdata in c drvie.Even if u didnot check if there is any mysql file in ur pc,Uninstall wamp and reinstall it,that may work.